# Rewrite fraction, probability generating function

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I'm looking at an example from probability (generating function) where the following fraction came up:

$g_Y(t)=\frac{q+tp}{2-p-tq}=\frac{1}{q(2-p)} (-p(2-p) + \frac{1}{1-\frac{qt}{2-p}})=\frac{1-p}{2-p}+\frac{t}{(2-p)^2}+\frac{qt^2}{(2-p)^3}+ \dots$

$p+q=1$

From which the probabilities $P(Y=1)$, $P(Y=2)$, etc, can be read out. My question is how one can from the fraction $\frac{q+tp}{2-p-tq}$ rewrite to another fraction that can be expanded as a geomteric series. I can of course check that their answer is correct, but what method should I use to tackle such a question if it comes up in a different form?

Comment: As coffeemath's answer says, there's a recipe in the case of generating functions of the form $a + \frac{b}{1-ct}$, and in practice this form of generating function should cover *most* of the things you encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that *if* it can be written as $a + b \frac{1}{1-ct}$ then expansion is possible, so equate your expression to this, cross multiply, and since in your expression the numerator and denominator are linear in $t$, you'll get to three equations in three unknowns $a,b,c$ for the coefficients (in terms of the constant coefficients $p,q$). Then solving that system will give the $a,b,c$, *hopefully*.